# What ZIF type connector is shown in this Canon Powershot G7X Camera?

Tags: connector, camera, ribbon-cable

I am modifying a Canon Powershot G7X camera so that I can couple the sensor to a tube lens and microscope objective. To do this conveniently I would like to extend the ribbon cable connected to the rear touch screen panel.

The connector for this looks like a so-called “zero insertion force” connector however I am not too familiar with these. Before buying an extender cable and pcb, can anyone help me identify the connector?
[image]

Circled you can see the connector and ribbon cable.  I have also taken two close-up shots. [image]
[image]

To be honest I am not sure I am even counting the number of pins correctly. I thought it would be 26 because of the exposed pins near the connector, but looking at the ribbon cable there seem to be more than that, possibly with some sort of keying.

Before I buy something like an adapter below I had better know what I am looking for first. [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a [bilevel back-flip* FFC socket](https://connectorbook.com/identification1.html?n=ffc_fpc_back_flip_sockets&f=jI) (my site).

(*) Funny name, ain't it?

I count 51 circuits.

You can find them here: https://www.digikey.com/short/vbq78jw5

- MANUF. - SERIES
- [Molex](https://www.molex.com/molex/products/family/easyon_ffc_fpc_connectors) - [Easy-on 502598 504740 504754](https://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/sd/5025982393_sd.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/b0230h37)
- [Molex](https://www.molex.com/molex/products/family/easyon_ffc_fpc_connectors) - [Easy-on 504070](https://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/sd/5040703991_sd.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/nrfjfwdh)
- Hirose Electric - [FH35](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Hirose%20PDFs/FH35_Series.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/r387zb8f)
- [Hirose Electric](https://www.hirose.com/en/product/series/FH35C) - [FH35C](https://www.hirose.com/en/product/document?clcode=&productname=&series=FH35C&documenttype=Catalog&lang=en&documentid=D49358_en) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/9vf40hv0)
- Hirose Electric - [FH39](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/185/hiros09581_1-2269477.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/z5w2v9m5)
- Hirose Electric - [FH39J](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/185/hiros09581_1-2269477.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/5708fp7r)
- Hirose Electric - [FH42](https://www.hirose.com/product/document?clcode=CL0580-2302-0-10&productname=FH42-15S-0.3SHW(10)&series=FH42&documenttype=Catalog&lang=en&documentid=D49361_en) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/db9dvzjj)
- [Hirose Electric](https://www.hirose.com/en/product/series/FH58) - [FH58 (0.2 mm)](https://www.hirose.com/en/product/document?clcode=&productname=&series=FH58&documenttype=Catalog&lang=en&documentid=en_FH58_FH58M_CAT) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/pjvt3p2d)
- [Hirose Electric](https://www.hirose.com/en/product/series/FH64MA) - [FH64MA](https://www.hirose.com/en/product/document?clcode=&productname=&series=FH64MA&documenttype=Catalog&lang=en&documentid=D162160_en) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/m3bjw53n)
- [JAE](https://www.jae.com/en/connectors/series/detail/id=64327&type_code=T1030) - [FR02](https://www.mouser.com/pdfdocs/JAEFR02FPCDatasheet.PDF) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/99tvq027)
- Omron - [XF2B](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/307/XF2B_1110-37066.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/375r7cbz)
- Omron - [XF3A](https://omronfs.omron.com/en_US/ecb/products/pdf/en-xf3a.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/741prwq1)
- Omron - [XF3B](https://omronfs.omron.com/en_US/ecb/products/pdf/en-xf3b.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/7nm5qcnm)
- Omron - [XF3C](https://omronfs.omron.com/en_US/ecb/products/pdf/en-xf3c.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/thqdqdm)
- Omron - [XF3Z](https://omronfs.omron.com/en_US/ecb/products/pdf/en-xf3z.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/02mw0440)
- Panasonic - [Y2B](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/315/con_eng_y2b-1518755.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/5chjp4d7)
- [Panasonic](https://na.industrial.panasonic.com/products/connectors/fpc-ffc-connectors/lineup/fpc-ffc/series/70457) - [Y3B](https://www3.panasonic.biz/ac/cdn/e/control/connector/fpc-ffc/catalog/con_eng_y3b.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/c9b1rq3b)
- Panasonic - [Y3BL](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/315/con_eng_y3bl-1397630.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/91v4v7pv)

To narrow it down, you will need to [measure the exact pitch](https://forum.digikey.com/t/pitch-of-a-connector/172). If you are unsure how to do that, measure the width of the cable (not at the tip with the notches) and we can do the rest. Also, whether the contacts are at the top or the bottom. And, you'll need to find one that locks onto the tabs on either side of the FPC (the "cable").

> Before I buy something like an adapter

Be aware that that might not work. An adapter (if you even find one, which is doubtful) adds capacitance, picks up noise, and causes reflections. The product may very well stop working.

> What ZIF type connector

Know that ZIP Is not a type of connector. It is a feature that many different connectors have. For example, [this ZIF DIP socket](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/9175) which doesn't look anything like an FFC socket. So, calling your socket a "ZIF connector" is not quite right.